# If $M$ is a finitely generated torsion module over a PID which is not a field then $M$ is Artinian.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $M$ is a finitely generated torsion module over a PID which is not a field then $M$ is Artinian.

Is contradiction the way to go? How does $M$ being torsion help us? Any hints on how to prove?

Comment: @Youngsu Well, $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is a counterexample to that... but nevertheless, using the structure theorem is the right way to go...

Comment: You are absolutely right. I should've said product of those. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does M being torsion help us?

I assume you are learning about the [fundamental structure theorem on f.g. modules over a PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain)?

The fact that the module is f.g. and torsion implies $M\cong \oplus_{i=1}^n R/(p_i^{e_i})$ for some primes $p_i$ in $R$ and exponents $e_i$.

> Any hints on how to prove?

You can check that each of these factors has finite composition length, and so the finite product of the factors has finite composition length.